# Overwriting in a faster way?

Tags: c++, c++11, ofstream

I am trying to write some text to a file, using ofstream method, but as I check the execution time, I can see that if the file doesn't exist, my program runs (in average) 7 seconds, and when the file exists, it runs in 20 seconds.

I have also tried removing and recreating the file if it exists. This takes that 7 seconds I was looking for.

Here my question is about the fastest way, so that whenever I rerun the code, the average time would be again about 7 seconds, without deleting the file first? And what is the reason of the extra time in overwriting a file?

The following code is what I used for creating the file streaming:

```
// remove("mytextfile.txt");
writer.open("mytextfile.txt", ofstream::out);
```

And I compiled my code this way:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp -O3
```

(My program runs on only one thread)

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what you're doing, like what OS you're using and a minimal code example that will let us reproduce the error?

Comment: First of all, there is no error (if I got you correctly). I am compiling and running my code in Ubuntu 16.04. The only thing that I am doing is writing 2.5 GB of characters into the file (and I have a 50 megabyte buffer in my code, for faster results)

Comment: @templatetypedef this isn't really an error- more of a question about how the code is behaving.  Your comment is really irrelevant.

Comment: Is the file huge? `open(fname, out)` may need to truncate the file to zero bytes, but that usually shouldn't take ~13 seconds. I'm curious what happens if you open it `ios::in|ios::out` (but only as a test! If the new output is shorter than the old output, this would incorrectly leave the end of the old file in place!)

Comment: @aschepler Using `ofstream::in | ofstream::out` gets the 7 second I was looking for! (Without the remove). Thanks man

Comment: @DerekBrown My apologies - I should have said "behavior" rather than "error."

Comment: Interesting, but you don't want to keep it that way, and I think @DerekBrown  has got the answer. So you can delete the old file from your code before opening (using C++17 `std::filesystem::remove`, POSIX `unlink`, `boost::filesystem::remove`, or etc.)  I guess an open can't do this by default since that would change what you can see from POSIX `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I surmise, the fastest way to do this is going to be a separate delete and overwrite operation. This is for two reasons:

1. Truncating a file (overwriting) and creating a new file work very differently.  When creating a new file, the application just allocates a new block for the file to reside.  When truncating, it must first perform a `fseek` to the end of the file, then write the new block. ([source](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/77092/))
2. C++ waits for the file descriptor to be closed before completing a disk operation.  If you trigger file deletion at the top of the file, the actual block-level operations operate asynchronously with your code, which then performs a new write.  If you use truncation, the application must wait for the file to be overwritten before writing which is a blocking operation. ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/865710/write-to-newfile-vs-overriding-performance-issue))